# Allow network user login via terminal

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

I accidentally deselected "Allow network user login at login window" on my mac. I need to restore that setting. I have admin and access to every file via the startup terminal utility (but can't login with my user name). How do enable network user login from the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

first:
`sudo /usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -a "com.apple.loginwindow.netaccounts" -t group "com.apple.access_loginwindow"`

then:
`sudo /usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -a "yourAccount" -t group "com.apple.loginwindow.netaccounts"`

Comment: When I tried `-a "yourAccount"` I got Record not found error.
For me worked with:
`sudo /usr/sbin/dseditgroup -o edit -u "userName" -t group "com.apple.loginwindow.netaccounts"`
after several restarts/hard shut down I got the checkbox back